# NagVis: Cannot load map because of error

Tags: monitoring, nagios

So, I have a NagVis map that I've been working on, and I've come across a very large problem. I was adding some text boxes in the map to label icons and eventually got an error

```
The attribute "text" is not supported in objects of type "global" on map map-01.
```

First, if I understand this error correctly, it means that "global" objects cannot be given text. However, I did not give any object text. I was creating standalone text boxes as I've done many times before on several maps. Of course I may have mis-clicked something while I was creating a text box, that's always a possibility, but I don't really understand what I've done wrong.

The more important issue is that I can no longer access this map. This error seems to have entirely cancelled all of my work because when I try to load that page, I get a pop-up giving me the error message again and the map does not load. It seems silly that a minor error would completely disable an entire map, so I have to believe there is a way to access this map and fix the issue - but I cannot find that way. The NagVis documentation and Google have not been able to help me with this, so I was hoping someone here could.

What I need is a way to get into this map and fix the error. Has anyone experienced this sort of issue before? If so, what can be done so that I don't have to completely start over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how this could happened, but you should be able to recover by modifying your map configuration file.

You should have a file like `/usr/local/nagvis-x.x/etc/maps/map-01.cfg`

Edit this file and you should find something like this in the `global` section definition :

```
define global {
grid_show=0
iconset=std_medium
text=MYTEXT
}
```

Remove `text=MYTEXT` from `global` section.

Comment: BRILLIANT! This worked perfectly. Thank you very very much for this. Such an easy solution to something I thought was much more complicated. I appreciate it very much.

Comment: On a side note: I'm not sure what happened, but somehow the global type also had a width/height, and x/y coordinates. It also had an object_id that looks more like other objects, rather than 0, and the iconset option was gone. So, it seems as though it was treating the map itself as an object within the map. If my understanding is wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The global config section contained one of the host config sections (the global setting were overwritten by one of the host settings). I deleted the whole global section and made a new one by copying it from an another map's config file. After the copy I reloaded the web page and i just had to reedit the map options.